# Dialogflow Java API returns weird string

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

Currently I'm using a Webhook API which has been deployed on GAE. The purpose is to use the slot filling function. The API supposed to return a fulfilment text to Dialogflow. However the problem occurs when it comes to display Thai language. Please see the attached files for reference. In Figure 1 you'll see that the response from Dialogflow API is unreadable as it has been encode in, I guess it's UTF-8. But in Figure 2 you can see that the API respond with a perfectly fine and readable Thai-Language. So my question is.

- How should I encode the character before post a response back from webhook to dialogflow?
- Is this a normal behaviour of Dialogflow?

[image: Figure1]

[image: Figure2]

Comment: Please make your final paragraph into its own question.  Each question should handle 1 problem.

Comment: will do, Thanks for the advice! I'm new to stackoverflow!